# web scraping in python with beautifulsoup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
install chromium, its driver, and selenium 
!apt update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver 
!pip install selenium 
# set options to be headless, .. 
from selenium import webdriver 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--headless') 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 

!sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta 
!sudo apt remove chromium-browser 
!sudo snap remove chromium 
!sudo apt install chromium-browser 

!pip3 install selenium 
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver 
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin 

import sys 
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver') 

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
wd.get("https://www.rusprofile.ru/?loggedout") 

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 
from time import sleep 
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
```

Code is working without mistakes until checking for credentials of personal account (selenium, python, colab google)

I'm trying to log in on the website with the code below and everything works fine until I'm trying to check if the logging in was successful or not

I press the button to call pop up with login form:

```
l = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="button"]') 
l.click()
```

then I find fields for email and password and fill them:

```
email=wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="email"]') # get the username field 
password=wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="password"]') # get the password field
email.send_keys("my-email") 
password.send_keys("my-password")
```

try to submit the form:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10) 
element_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn btn-blue"]'))) 
element_button.click()
```

and then check if the logging in was successful by checking that html has my name and surname:

```
my_element = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Myfirstname Mysurname']") 
my_element
```

It works every other time and I don't know if there any mistake before last step or it is website protection.
Please, help me to find a solution how I can log in every time without mistakes

Comment: Will it login successfully each time? I mean manually if you check the browser, do you see your username? Also, can you share the error stack?

Comment: I made a screenshot and it turned out that additional pop up with warning was called, that was a cause of the error with checking for credentials of personal account.
I added additional click on the button for skipping the warning and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the wait you use here:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10) 
element_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn btn-blue"]')))
```

during all the other actions you perform like:

```py
element_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Myfirstname Mysurname']")))
```

Remember to change the value from `element_to_be_clickable` to `visibility_of_element_located` if you're not looking for buttons.
You should be utilising waits at every step of your script/test to make sure that the elements you want to work with are actually there.

Comment: I've tried your advice, but TimeoutException error comes out

Comment: That means the element is not being found, try making the time it will wait higher, for example: ```wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)```, handle the exception inside of a try: except block and retry, or try to find out exactly why the element is not being found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and works fine until checking for the name of your user. Try to locate with the full xpath, works fine for me:

```
my_element = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]/span") 

my_element.text
```

And with that you get the plain text of your user

EDIT:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.get("https://www.rusprofile.ru/?loggedout") 
l = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="button"]') 
l.click()

email=wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="email"]') # get the 
username field 
password=wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="password"]') # get the 
password field
email.send_keys("pep@yopmail.com") 
password.send_keys("123456Aa!")
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10) 
element_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//[@class="btn btn-blue"]'))) 
element_button.click()

time.sleep(2)

try:
    my_element = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]/span") 
    my_element.text

except:


    l = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[6]') 
    l.click()



time.sleep(2)
my_element = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]/span") 
my_element.text
```

This one works to skip the pop up. If there is a pop up skip it, if doesn´t show get the username. Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried your advice but NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @user21139164 - How did you login without the username and password?

Comment: I created a fake username for this.

@anonim worked the first time I used it( returns empty str if the browser is not maximized, if it´s maximazed returns the string).

But the second time I tried there is a pop up saying something in russian, try to locate the button and skip that pop up:

l = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[6]') 
l.click()

That one worked for me.